# How to embed maven modules as .class dependencies as opposed to jars?

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project that is used to produce a single spring boot fat jar. My project looks something like this.

```
 - Parent Module Aggergator 
    - A 
    - B
    - C 
    - app <-- app.jar is the only thing I want to publish
```

In my case module A, B, C are only ever used by app and should not be published into maven repo. I have split up the app into multi-module project because it's a lot of code in the app and it's to work with that way.

Currently the `app.jar` will contain inside it `a.jar, b.jar c.jar`.

Is there a way to tell maven that the compiled classes from module A, B, C should just be inserted into app.jar classes folder without ever producing A.JAR, B.JAR, C.JAR?

Comment: I think the Maven Shade plugin creates a single JAR file by extracting the contents of all the dependent jar and then creating a single JAR file with all that content together - but this is not quite what you want...

Comment: The question is: What is the problem with deploying the A, B, C jar into a maven repo? You are deploying the resulting app.jar ? Going away from conventions over configurations makes it more difficult to maintain such things and makes it harder for other to understand...

Answer (score 2):

I use the Maven Shade Plugin for my multi-module project; it creates a single JAR and extracts each module into it rather than creating multiple JAR files:

Parent `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipeline</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>firehose</module>
        <module>gson</module>
        <module>lambda</module>
        <module>mapper</module>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>receiver</module>
        <module>redshift</module>
        <module>reloader</module>
        <module>s3</module>
        <module>sns</module>
        <module>sqs</module>
        <module>systemstests</module>
        <module>transaction</module>
        <module>utility</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child `pom.xml` (the JAR):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>pipeline</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                   <finalName>MyJar</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non answer.

> Is there a way to tell maven that the compiled classes from module A,
>   B, C should just be inserted into app.jar classes folder without ever
>   producing A.JAR, B.JAR, C.JAR?

You could use [the `repackage` goal of the spring boot maven plugi](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)n that flatten the dependencies into classes in the uber jar.

> In my case module A, B, C are only ever used by app and should not be
>   published into maven repo.

Adding the modules in a local repository is really wanted to have a **efficient** and **standard** build.
Without that, you will need to compile systematically each module at each time you want to run your spring boot app.
While actually sometimes you need to build dependencies, but other times you don't need because these are already updated.
Or else you will be constraint to twist the default Maven way of work by adding manual tasks to compile from the spring boot module the other modules and to move the compiled classes into the spring boot module. Really not a gift for the people that will have to read/maintain this configuration.